# Github Actions create-react-app build step fails only in pipeline but not on local machine

Tags: reactjs, github, webpack, github-actions

I am running a GitHub Actions build step to install npm dependencies and build the react app. My build runs fine on my windows machine but fails in Githubs Ubuntu virtual machine. The error I get is:

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom'. '/home/runner/work/React-Portfolio/React-Portfolio/client/node_modules/react-dom/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

"Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-dom'"

I have @types/react, and @types/react-dom listed in the package.json, however the issue persists.

Adding a type declaration seems like a hack any better ways to do this?

Comment: I got it to work with adding a type declaration: `declare module 'react-dom'` but this feels like a hack.